# How is this possible, object should not exist in ModelState?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im wondering if Im confused or the microsoft documentation is incorrect...

On my view I have the code:

```
ViewData.ModelState[""].Errors
```

The last bit comes up in intellisense but when I look at the documentation for the class ModelState I dont see it...

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.modelstate%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Am I missing something?

Also why is ModelState a dictionary and then errors shouldnt it be access the errors then look at the specific entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelState you see in your controller is one of these:

```
ModelStateDictionary : IDictionary<string, ModelState>
```

So you have a dictionary by form field name with a complex object as its value. ModelState is defined as:

```
    public ValueProviderResult Value {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ModelErrorCollection Errors {
        get {
            return _errors;
        }
    }
```

If you want to look at your ModelState from an errors perspective rather than from a keys perspective, you could always use some Linq to find them all:

```
var errs = ModelState.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Errors);
```

(Note that I haven't tested that Linq - it's just an idea :)